# ListPlot from Table of single input x and many y(x) output

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

Suppose have data for several x and several y(x), for example

```
mydata = {{11, 1.1, 2.3, 2.4}, {12, 1.3, 1.4, 1.9}, {13, 1.8, 1.7, 1.2}}
mydata // MatrixForm
```

So

for x=11, have y(x)= 1.1, 2.3 and 2.4

for x=12, have y(x)= 1.3, 1.4 and 1.9

for x=13, have y(x)= 1.8, 1.7 and 1.2

How to do list plot for many y(x) as function of x?

Use of

```
ListPlot[mydata]
```

is no working.

Comment: Related: [(21884)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21884/121), [(47038)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47038/121)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mydata2 = Thread[{First@#, Rest@#}] & /@ mydata;
ListPlot[mydata2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
mydata2 = Map[(mydata[[All, {1, #}]]) &, Range[2, Last@Dimensions@mydata]];
ListPlot[mydata2, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Notice how your image is very similar to Mr.Wizard's image. Still, you image somehow appears to be of lower visual quality; it looks 'fuzzy' or something. Why is that? Well, this is because you saved it as a JPG image. JPG works well with photographic images, but introduces artefacts in illustrations, diagrams, screenshots, etc. For this kind of images, PNG is the ideal choice! :)

Answer (score 2):

Not applicable to all data, but in this case [`DataRange`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DataRange.html) appears useful:

```
ListLinePlot[mydata\[Transpose][[2 ;;]], DataRange -> {11, 13}]
```

[image]